# Global.asax Session_End not fired on Session.Abandon() with enableSessonState=ReadOnly

Tags: asp.net, session

I am trying to perform cleanup tasks via `Global.asax.Session_End()` after my ASP.Net Session was terminated via `Session.Abandon()`.

I have ensured the following

- SessionStateMode is *InProc*
- I wrote data into the SessionDataStore
  (`Session["foo"] = "bar"`)
- Session creation and .Abandon() are performed in different requests, the session is persisted

Now I am experiencing the following behavior:
When I make the session writable globally (`enableSessionState = true` in web.config) my `Global.asax.Session_End()` is triggered shortly after `Session.Abandon()` as expected.

However, when I set `enableSessionState = ReadOnly` in web.config and only allow certain pages to add data to the session via `EnableSessionState="true`, e.g.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebPages_Login" EnableSessionState="true"%>
```

`Global.asax.Session_End()` is not triggered after `Session.Abandon()` but only after the session times out.

How can I trigger `Global.asax.Session_End()` on `Session.Abandon()` with  `enableSessionState = ReadOnly` set globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to dig deeper into this.

When Session.Abandon() is triggered from pages with EnableSessionState=ReadOnly, the InProcSessionState is not marked as locked (_locked=false).

This only happens if EnableSessionState=true for the request which triggers Session.Abandon()

From System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionStateStore.DoGet(...):

```
if (exclusive) {
                lockedByOther = true;

                // If unlocked, use a spinlock to test and lock the state.
                if (!state._locked) {
                    state._spinLock.AcquireWriterLock();
                    try {
                        if (!state._locked) {
                            lockedByOther = false;
                            state._locked = true;
                            state._utcLockDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                            state._lockCookie++;
                        }
                        lockId = state._lockCookie;
                    }
                    finally {
                        state._spinLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
                    }
                }
```

System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState() fires _store.RemoveItem() for the session if it is abandoned. However, this RemoveItem() is only executed, if the current InProcSessionState is locked. See InProcSessionStateStore.RemoveItem():

```
            try {
            /* Only remove the item if we are the owner */
            if (!state._locked || state._lockCookie != lockCookie)
                return;

            /* prevent overwriting when we drop the lock */
            state._lockCookie = 0;
        }
```

So, in this situation (EnableSessionState=ReadOnly) Session.Abandon() simply does not abandon the session. Looks like an ASP.Net bug to me.

Hence what I had to do was trigger the cleanup code twice:

- Direcly where System.Abandon() is called
- in Global.asax.Session_End() for timed out sessions

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup to the OP. Some handlers in my app use read-only session state. However, I found that the event names in .NET have apparently changed (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx). After implementing both Session_OnStart and Session_OnEnd my sessions are terminated correctly and do call Session_OnEnd. I do not store any items in the session state. So I believe that is not necessary.